# How to host a website from my own PC

Tags: webserver, hosting, web-hosting

I want to host my website from my own PC.

I have biought a unique IP address, but I don't know how to create DNS entries or how to create name server.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Google search for "LAMP Server" is you're running Linux or instead search for "WAMP Server" if you're running Windows.  Keep in mind that running a web-server is no trivial matter.  People go to school for years for it and still don't know everything.  Google "web hosting basics" would probably help too.

Comment: @headkase Ok, Thanks, My ip address is fixed and that is config by my ISP, and I just install XAMPP server in my PC, and when I enter my IP Fixed IP address it's work very well but I want to attach my domain into that.....

Comment: @Jasmin I understand that you have a permanent IP. What you need is to point your domain to the IP that you have . In the Admin Panel of the domain seller there will be a place to point the domain to a particular Ip address.

Try this and it will work for you...

Thanks

Comment: @Joe: Ok, but how setup NAME SERVER, and Have another problem, I have 3 website but I have Only one IP address, how to separate 3 website in one IP address?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of steps both on your domain name control panel side, your home Internet modem/router side and the PC you wish to act as the web server you're trying to set up.

First things first, well done for getting a static IP from your ISP - this will help you immensely in reducing the steps!

**Domain name control panel**

1. Log on to domain name control panel - this is usually the company who you bought the domain name through
2. Look for DNS settings where you will already have - or have to create - TWO "**A (address)**" records. These are **@** and **www** respectively.
3. When the A records ask for an IP this is where you enter your ISP's static IP (the one to your home Internet). An example for Namecheap can be found here: https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1162/46/how-can-i-point-my-domain-name-to-my-home-servers-ip
4. Save the settings - please note that the changes may not work immediately as they have to propagate through other services.

**Your PC (the machine you wish to host your website)**

1. Assign the PC a static IP that is within your DHCP subnet but not within the DHCP scope - For example your router will dish out 192.168.0.2-254 (with 192.168.0.1 being the router itself (gateway). in this instance you will need to log in to your router interface and change the scope so that the DHCP pool isn't so big. Change it to, say, 192.168.0.2-100. You can then give your PC a static IP of anything between 192.168.0.101-254. Alternatively you can "reserve" the currently assigned DHCP address your router has assigned your PC. Any time your PC re-connects it will always be given the same IP - for home use this is perfectly acceptable and may be more convenient.
2. Configure your web server (e.g. Apache) to be "put online" - change the configuration so that is listens to 0.0.0.0 on port 80.

**Your home router**

1. Log on to your home router web interface
2. Set up a port forward for port 80 (HTTP) to the static IP of the PC you want to be the web server.

Comment: OK, Sir, Thank you, Sir, can you tell me What kind of Internet speed I need for hosing, I have 1000 visitor par day, And currently I use 2 Mbps Net connection and my upload speed is 1 Mbps.

Comment: This all depends on whether your visitors are connecting simultaneously and the amount of data they are obtaining from your website (for example, does your website have lost of images, videos, downloadables, CSS, JavaScript etc. A 1Mbps might not be so great and your visitors may experience some slow response times... if I were hosting a website with such volume I'd look at hosting my site with a dedicated hosting company - they're not that expensive.